# is template <typename T=char> correct?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T=char>
```

I saw this code in some porjects.
Why does he/she put "=char" their?
Is this legal, How does it mean?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a default value for the template parameter, so it can be instantiated without having to specify that type.

```
template <typename T=char>
class Foo { ... };

Foo<> x;      // a Foo<char>
Foo<char> y;  // same as above
Foo<int> z;   // now a Foo<int>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to set default values or types for class template parameters.

```
template <class T=char, int N=10> class mysequence {..};
```

We could create objects using the default template parameters by declaring:

```
 mysequence<> myseq;
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
mysequence<char,10> myseq;
```